# An example of Dijkstra's algorithm to fail with one negative edge

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, dijkstra

I'm trying to think of a graph which all edges have positive weights, except of one edge such that Dijkstra's algorithm fails to produce the correct output.

I'd be glad for an idea.

**EDIT:**
I've seen this graph as a counter-example but I don't understand why. 
The vertex `A` would be the last to pop-out from the queue and then we will `Relax()` the edge `A->E`. So the path `S->A->E` will be chosen, which is the correct path (And not `S->B->E` as was claimed)

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra terminates upon expanding the goal node. Also we use a priority queue in dijkstra (not a queue) so that we expand the node that has the least cost. So in your example A will never be expanded.

```
  open list = [ S cost:0 ] // priortiy queue
pop S out of open list
  closed list = [ S cost:0 ]
  open list = [ B cost:1 ; A cost:5 ]
pop B out of open list
  closed list = [ S cost:0 ; B cost:1 ]
  open list = [ E cost:2 ; A cost:5 ]
pop E out of open list
// it's better to terminate when we reach the goal but if we don't
// it doesn't make any difference we are going to find the shortest path
// to other nodes
   closed list = [ S cost:0 ; B cost:1 ; E cost:2 ]
   open list = [ A cost:5 ]
pop A out of open list
   // there isn't any nodes that we can push to open list
   closed list = [ S cost:0 ; B cost:1 ; E cost:2 ; A cost:5 ]
   open_list = []
```

Dijkstra push a node to its closed list upon expanding it because it assumes it has find the shortest path to it. So even if we don't terminate upon reaching a goal we will never expand A because it is in our closed list.

Comment: What do you mean by "the goal node"? I know that Dijkstra's algorithm terminates when the priority-queue is empty.

Comment: I'll explain it in my answer shortly.

Comment: CLRS book says otherwise. We add a vertex to the closed set iff it got out of the priority-queue.

Comment: "CLRS book says otherwise. We add a vertex to the closed set iff it got out of the priority-queue" That is exactly what I said, expanding means poping a node out of the p-queue and adding\updating its neighbors in open list.

Comment: Alright, but anyway - if you agree that the vertex `A` will popped-out at some point then you should realize that the `A->E` edge will be "relaxed" and so, the `S->A->E` path will be chosen.

Comment: No `E` is already in the closed list it won't change anymore. That is the whole point behind the closed list. We won't relax edges to nodes that are in closed list.

Comment: @Elimination Anyway if you want to relax nodes indefinitely you will have `Bellman-Ford` algorithm which works on graphs with negative and positive edges.

Comment: But `A` isn't in the closed-set right? And you popped it out from the p-queue. Right? so you will relax the edge `A->E`. No doubt.

Comment: NO, IT WONT ! Run any implementation of dijkstra you can find and see it for yourself. http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Dijkstra's_algorithm